XStreamに用意されている変換クラスを利用して２つのパターンをアンマーシャルしたいのですが、うまくいかないです。
XML側をせずにアンマーシャルを可能にしたいのですが、用意されているクラスだとできないのでしょうか？もしかして自作する必要がありますかね？
パターン１
<value>Hello</value>

パターン２
<value>
  <expression>
    map.message
  </expression>
</value>

モデル
@XStreamAlias("value")
@XStreamConverter(value = ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings = "text")
class ValueNode {

  private String text;

  private ExpressionNode node;
　
　// それぞれの setter / getter
}
@XStreamAlias("expression")
@XStreamConverter(value = ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings = "text")
class ExpressionNode {

  private String text;

　// それぞれの setter / getter
}

アンマーシャル後の期待したデータ




ValueNode.text
ValueNode.node
ExpressionNode.text




パターン１
"Hello"
null
-


パターン２
null
インスタンス
"map.message"



アンマーシャル後の実際のデータ




ValueNode.text
ValueNode.node
ExpressionNode.text




パターン１
"Hello"
null
-


パターン２
"\n\t\n"
null
-



